# Populate parameter in Tableau dynamically

Tags: tableau-api

How can I populate default value of float parameter from back end dynamically?
I have single value drop down for client selection corresponding discount is in database which I want pull and show as default value in parameter box.
I am using Tableau 9

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic parameters are not currently supported in Tableau. It is one of the most requested features. With that said, there are some hacks out that may or may not work in your specific use case. Take a look at the results of this [google search](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=tableau%20dynamic%20parameters&oq=tableau%20dyna&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3864j0j7) and perhaps you might find something you can use.

Answer (score 1):

In Tableau 9 the dynamic parameter feature is not supported.

Why are you not trying a simple filter and making that filter as a single select for client and similarly for a single select discount and cascade the filters.

i.e. select show relevant values for discount filter.

What this will do is, when you select a particular client it will show the value in discount box the value corresponding to that on client(as you have made client filter as a single select it will show only one value).